# C# authentication issues after upgrading 'DependencyInjection'

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core

I'm working on a solution that uses both .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1 for the projects. I've recently had to upgrade the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to version 3.0.0 from 2.2.0. However, now I have a runtime error whenever I try to access an endpoint:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandlerProvider' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Now, when I search online I can't find much except for the Microsoft documentation and a definition mentioned in a GitHub post where it simply says it should `provide the AuthenticationHandler` and that it is `responsible for returning the correct handler instance for a given scheme and request.`, respectively.

It obviously breaks on the Invoke call from the AuthenticationMiddleware class, but I believe I read somewhere that you shouldn't create your own authenticationmiddleware lightly and that the class should work 'out of the box', so I'm not too sure how to go about fixing this issue.

I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with authentication, so I'm not sure what code you will require to spot the problems. If there's anything crucial missing please comment and I will add it. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create a new MVC project using .NET Core 3.0/3.1 with Individual authentication and then compare the `Startup.cs` from the new project with the one from the existing project to see what's different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a solution that uses both .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1 for the projects. I've recently had to upgrade the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to version 3.0.0 from 2.2.0. However, now I have a runtime error whenever I try to access an endpoint:

System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandlerProvider' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
Now, when I search online I can't find much except for the Microsoft documentation and a definition mentioned in a GitHub post where it simply says it should provide the AuthenticationHandler and that it is responsible for returning the correct handler instance for a given scheme and request., respectively.

It obviously breaks on the Invoke call from the AuthenticationMiddleware class, but I believe I read somewhere that you shouldn't create your own authenticationmiddleware lightly and that the class should work 'out of the box', so I'm not too sure how to go about fixing this issue.

I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with authentication, so I'm not sure what code you will require to spot the problems. If there's anything crucial missing please comment and I will add it. Any and all help is much appreciated.